# How can I set a unix binary as a default application in Mac OS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, unix

I want to configure mupdf to be my default PDF viewer in Mac OS, but it's a unix console executable located in /usr/local. The traditional "Open with" method does not work, as Finder will not allow you to select the binary. How can one do this?

Comment: Never tried it for this specific case, but [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) has been the go-to for that, since ... forever. Freeware, still works on mojave. Check it out & let us know...

Comment: Well, it looks like a cool solution, but it still won't allow me to select a UNIX executable from, say, /usr/local/bin. The finder window deactivates (grays-out) the files so that they can't be selected, and RCDefaultApp doesn't allow me to enter a path to the file. So, on the face of it, this doesn't do what I need unless there's some trick to it.

Comment: you could define an alias like mu2 to be equal to the path and file name of mupdf. Then typing the alias should run the app.

Comment: I can run mupdf just fine, no alias needed. I just can't seem to set it as a default application so that when I double-click a PDF in Finder it uses mupdf instead of Preview to open it.